# Write a shell function from the current shell script to antoher shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, zsh

I have a zsh shell script that looks as following:

```
# ! /usr/bin/env zsh
my_function () {
    echo "my function is running"
    python3 my_python_script.py
}
```

I would like to call this script and copy the function `my_function` to `<file_location>/test.sh`.

My current attempt looks as following:

```
# ! /usr/bin/env bash
BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")

cat <<EOF > $BASEDIR/test.sh
my_function () {
    echo "my function is running"
    output_string=\$(python3 my_python_script.py);
}
EOF
```

Is it possible copy this function, ideally without turning the entire function into a string first?

EDIT: Added missing dollarsign with escape that caused python script to be called intstead of copied as a string

Comment: `this causes bash to try to execute python3 my_python_script.py` this is odd, no, I don't think that happens. Your script should be fine and write to `test.sh` file.

Comment: Why not just copy the script?

Answer (score 0):

While I wouldn't recommend using this method for anything other than testing purposes, you *can* achieve this goal via the `type` command.

```sh
# cat test.sh
testfunc() {
        echo "Running testfunc"
}

# Append the function definition to tmp.sh, using tail to skip the 'testfunc is a function' line
type testfunc | tail -n +2 >> tmp.sh
# ./test.sh
# cat tmp.sh
testfunc ()
{
    echo "Running testfunc"
}
```